# Java Thread ID: Very high numbers

Tags: java, multithreading, jmx

I have a Java web application (1.8) running in a Tomcat. The application logs to a log file, including the thread-ID:
06/30 11:30:51 (**101970**) [userInfo Jun 30 11:30:51 CEST 2022] INFO  some.class.name [] - Some Log Message

I recently noticed that the Thread-Id has become very large (1600000 +) and wonder if that indicates a problem with the Threadpooling (i.e. threads not being returned to the pool).

According to the Thread class, the ID should be a unique number that is increasing (and might be reused). I assumed that this means that the ID should increase only if a new additional Thread had to be created.

However, I am currently monitoring the Thread counts (via ThreadMXBean) and see that the thread-id-number is much higher than the Peak Thread Count.

Does anyone have insights of how the thread-id is created and if there is any correlation between a high thread id and the number of threads?

Comment: Are you worried that some kind of problem will occur if the ID gets too high?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `java.lang.Thread` we see the following very simple little piece of code:

```
/* For generating thread ID */
private static long threadSeqNumber;

private static synchronized long nextThreadID() {
    return ++threadSeqNumber;
}
```

What this means is that every time a new thread is created, a new id is issued, regardless of whether previously created threads have terminated or not. What this means is that a thread id will never be reused, and I would speculate that thread id is `long` for the sole purpose of guaranteeing that you will never run out of thread ids.

Now, thread-pools as well as other functionalities of the JVM create and destroy threads all the time. For example, if a thread pool has not had any use for one of its threads for some time, it may destroy that thread, and re-create it later, when it discovers that it has a use for it.

This means that as your software keeps running for hours, you will inevitably be seeing higher and higher thread ids. That's normal.

Comment: In theory, a thread id could get reused if your application is long-lived enough, and your thread creation frequency high enough, to overflow (wrap around) the counter. Also, the java documentation describes API of what you should account for (e.g. the implementation might change to use a different method of accounting/generating of thread ids, which could cause it to reuse ids earlier)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, in theory. In exactly the same way that in theory, it is possible that a GUID may be identical to a previously issued one. But in practice, it cannot happen.

Comment: I cannot be bothered to do the math right now, but I would be willing to bet that if you are spawning threads as fast as you can, (threads which immediately terminate, so that you do not run out of memory,) thread creation still takes a sufficiently long number of milliseconds that your thread ids would reach `Long.MaxValue` after the inevitable heat death of the universe, or at the very least after the sun has exploded and swallowed our planet.

Comment: Or the earth is swallowed by an enormous mutant star-goat ([ref](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Golgafrincham)) ...

Comment: Don't know about the heat death of the universe, but the Sun is on-track to engulf the Earth in approximately 1.58e17 seconds from now. So long as the program does not create more than about 116 threads per second on average, we won't have to worry about the `threadSeqNumber` wrapping around before then.

Comment: @SolomonSlow thanks for doing the math. Wow, that's about one thread per 10 milliseconds, and although it is within same the order of magnitude as what I anticipated, threads can probably be created and destroyed at a rate which is somewhat faster than that, so yes: I admit: if you start ***today*** creating threads as fast as you can, you might run out of thread ids shortly ***before*** the inevitable-due-to-forces-majeures end of your employment contract.